# adding a user in django admin is impossible

Tags: django

I created a customuseradmin model and add a field (age) to it . now when i want to add a user despite using legal characters for username,  it gives me error in django admin panel and want me to correct username

here is the code of my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and the view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

and form as well

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields+('age',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

and also admin file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'age', 'is_staff', ]  # list of fields that displays in admin panel
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets+((None, {'fields': ('age',)}),)
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets+((None, {'fields': ('age',)}),)


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

any answer would be appreciated
Thanks

i did not find any answer after a couple of hours searching the internet

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting and in which of those views. Your custom signup view or the django admin?

Comment: it says please correct the error below and point mo to the username textbox and the error occers in both of them

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, your file admin.py with registered models in admin panel. It should be like that:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomUser


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: i edited my question and put admin file content

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your settings.py defining the AUTH_USER_MODEL property.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.CustomUser'
```

Comment: I did not post my settings.py but i made this update befor